# create panel page for taxonomy term page

Tags: 8, panels

How to create panel for taxonomy term page using [Page Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager) in Drupal 8.
I've created page with path `/taxonomy/term/{taxonomy_term}` but it doesn't work and displays default taxonomy page template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get this to work with the latest dev versions of `Panels` and `Page Manager`. Here are the key pieces:

- Disable the `Taxonomy term` view.
- Set the path on the panels page to `/taxonomy/term/%`.
- Clear cache.
- View page at `taxonomy/term/{tid}`.
- I verified that this also works with URL aliases.

One thing to keep in mind: If you use selection conditions (e.g. by Vocabulary), terms that don't satisfy the selection conditions return a 404 (which may or may not be what you want). There is an [issue on Drupal.org for providing a default fallback](https://www.drupal.org/node/2820218).

Comment: How do I common block for all the taxonomy term page. ?

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8.4.4 and Page Manager I have set path for page to /taxonomy/term/{taxonomy_term} and disable view "Taxonomy term" and page works (for one taxonomy term).

Answer (score 0):

As dobrzyns implied, the panels taxonomy page template in Panels conflicts with the Views Taxonomy page.  However, rather than disabling the goodness of the Views Taxonomy Page view, you can change the default Views Taxonomy Page View path to something like 'view/taxonomy/term/%'.  This gives you the flexibility of adding the the Views Taxonomy Page view as content within your Panels pages.